# I can't open a WebSocket connection in HTTPS

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services, websocket

I have a problem involving WebSockets, I recently added HTTPS to my website, and it seems that I am not able to establish a connection with WebSockets due to HTTPS, because with HTTP I was able to. Well, I already tried to make the server listen to port 8080 (but says it is already in use), I also tried port 8443 and 3000 (when trying with these two, I get an opening handshake timed out error), so I really don't I know what to do, I believe my wss url is right, I don't really understand ports and which port I should use together with HTTPS to start a connection with the WebSocket
Note: The server starts normally when using port 8443 or 3000, I am using the PHP Ratchet library, however, in the browser it does not start and reports an error

> Error: failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out (chrome console)
>
> JavaScript: var conn = new WebSocket ("wss://example.net:8443/
> chat.php");

Comment: Just a thought. Shouldn't `var conn = new WebSocket ("wss: //example.net: 8443 / chat.php");` be `var conn = new WebSocket ("wss://example.net:8443/chat.php");`, URL without spaces.

Comment: Yeah I know, I am using this way

Comment: Is it a problem with ports? If yes, which one should I use? I see there's nothing wrong in my code, it looks like ports error